# Jquery - Building variable name from multiple <option> selection

Tags: jquery

Semi-hypothetical question, let's say I have multiple strings, one of which may need to be displayed based on what dropdown choices are made. What I'me thinking of is something along the following:

```
var 11 = "fast cars"
var 12 = "slow cars"
var 21 = "fast bikes"
var 22 = "slow bikes"
```

The string that gets displayed is then selected by the combination of two boxes:

```
<select id="type">
<option value="1">automobiles</option>
<option value="2">motorbikes</option>
</select>
<select id="type2">
<option value="1">get there fast</option>
<option value="2">be comfortable</option>
</select>
```

In my main body I have code that constantly refers to a variable "transtype". What I'd like to be able to do is link the variable "transtype" to one of the variable string above, i.e.:

```
var one = $( "#type" ).val();
var two = $( "#type2" ).val();
var fullvarname = [one + two];
var transtype = fullvarname;
```

What I'm getting, at the moment, is the variable "transtype" echoing out "11" or "21", etc. and not the string that the variable should link to. Obviously this is because the code sees the concatenated values as string. The question is, how do I get it to recognize it as a name of a variable and not a string itself?

As a caveat, I'd like to point out that there are actually around half a dozen boxes with several options each. To try and have one dropdown with all possible combinations would be hideous. Also, the required string (e.g. "fast cars" is actually a whole bunch more that includes { and [). I'm also keen on using jquery so that I can update content on the fly without having to reload the entire page a la PHP.

I'm new to Javascript/jquery and this is one of very few areas that I've not been able to work out from other posts here and elsewhere. If the above is not possible, or if it can be better achieved via a different method, please feel free to say...

Comment: If you want the text value, rather than the actual value then just use `.text()` instead of `.val()`.  And Java != Javascript ;)

Comment: Take your point about "Java" :D, however I'm not after the text value of the dropdown. Maybe I should have given the example the other way around, with the options being "fast" "car" and the resulting string being "you like to drive cars quickly", based on the concatenated selected values.

Comment: Apart from your example variable names being illegal in JavaScript – _whenever_ you think about “numbering” of variable names, an _array_ is the better choice (in at least 99.99…999% of cases). So go use one instead.

Comment: Thanks for feedback, the answer below has worked perfectly for what I need...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to access variables using string values, you can try wrapping the variables(11,12...) inside an object, and then accessing them using the `obj[keyString]` syntax.

So, something like:

```
var names = {};
names["11"] = "fast cars";
names["12"] = "slow cars";
names["21"] = "fast bikes";
names["22"] = "slow bikes";
```

ought to work. Access them with `names[one+two]`

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/w99wq/)